# integers numbers Roots of Polynomials in python

Tags: python, list, google-colaboratory

I have to write a function that takes a parameter p with the list representing the polynomial p(x) and returns the canonical list of the entire roots of p(x). For example, the polynomial with the coefficients [1, -5, 6] must return the roots [2, 3]. I must use lists and consider that the first coefficient will always be 1.

```
degree = int(input('degree: '))
p=[]
i=0
while i <= degree:     #creates polynomial
  coef = int(input("Coef: "))
  p.append(coef)
  i+=1 
               # creates p(possible roots)

pê=[0]
for x in range(1,p[-1]):
  if b % x == 0:
    pê.append(-x)
    pê.append(x)
for g in pê:
```

Comment: What is your question specifically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy for this.

```
import numpy as np
coeff=[1,-5,6]
roots=np.roots(coeff)
```